# Overwrite Image Size with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, mobile-website

I am trying to make images in mobile theme of the blog to fit the mobile screen. I am referring to images inside the articles and not the ones that are part of theme like the header etc.

One of the problem I am getting is that blog software automatically adds the height and width in pixel. This is how the source code looks like:

```
<div class="leftbox"><img src=".mysite.net/blog/media/Photo/Indian_tourists.jpg" width="400" height="267" alt="Indian tourists" title="Indian tourists" /></div>
```

I want to use the css to overwrite image code with max-width: 100% so that in case the image is larger than the screen size, it could fix in it.

Someone told me to put the following code at the bottom of mobile theme css file.

```
.post_content img {
height: auto !important;
max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

I tried this code but unfortunately it didn't work out. Could someone please help me with it.

Comment: can you use JS to drop those attributes?

Comment: Sorry but I am not an expert. Could you please explain that?

Comment: You don't need to be an expert. http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/

Answer (score 0):

if your div class is leftbox then you can use the following code in your css file

```
.leftbox img {
   height: auto !important;
   max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: ok can you show me the whole hosted page URL so that i can tell you how it can be done.

Comment: This is the url but you will have to access it from mobile device otherwise desktop site will show up. http://www.easydestination.net/blog/index.php?itemid=3162

Comment: i think it is showing fine the image is in the middle and it not going outside the viewing area of the screen.  
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6kijBBg7XLsY3JXQU9mLTdpZmVEak0wcktWYl82eGt2Mlhv/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is your device and browser? I am using Opera Mini on Android OS and its not working here

Comment: Okay its working on Chrome OS for Android but not on Opera Mini. Similarly I tried online simulator for iPhone. Here it is not working on iPhone 5 while working on iPhone 3. How to fix that?

Comment: i have iphone 4 and 4s it is working in both the browsers let me check in the Opera Mini

Comment: working file in opera mini also  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6kijBBg7XLsTzJuLXhtWXpjblhkRlpOaGgzb0xuakkxYzNv/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That's strange because its not working from my phone's opera mini and my brother's. I guess its a a cache issue or something. Thank you for all the help. Just one more thing, my idiot brother has posted some articles in which images aren't posted in leftbox div. In such case should I simply paste the code you gave in css excluding .leftbox to get it work? This is one of the articles I am referring to http://www.easydestination.net/blog/?itemid=829

Comment: for this you can use post_content as class name

    .post_content img {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <div class="leftbox"><img src=".mysite.net/blog/media/Photo/Indian_tourists.jpg"     width="400" height="267" alt="Indian tourists" title="Indian tourists" /></div>
```

css

```
 .leftbox img
  {   height: auto !important;
     width: 100% !important;
  }
```

or add this css file

```
  img[style] {
    height:auto !important;
    max-width:100% !important;
  }
```

Comment: Changing image tag would be difficult since I will have to do manually on over 3000 articles. I tried the second option but its not working across platforms. For example it fixes the image in Chrome OS but not on Opera Mini.

Comment: 2nd option is the best method and it is compatible with all major desktop browsers.. i don't know about mobile browsers. i made some change in first option.. plz try that

Comment: Thanks Justin the second option (.leftbox) which you and Usman suggested has worked for me. Thanks for all the help.